# Sequential UITableView navigation with floating UIView / UIButton

Tags: iphone, uikit

I've got a series of UITableViews (Child A, B, C) which all have a common parent Tableview.
Navigating between children tableviews will be sequential (e.g. following a recipe).

At the moment, navigation looks like this:
Starting in Parent TableView (Rows Child A, B, C):
    Select Child A -> Push Child A -> View Child A -> click Return to pop Child A and return to Parent
    Repeat for Child B, C

However, what would be neat is if we could navigate like this:
Starting in Parent TableView (Rows Child A, B, C):
    Select Child A -> Push Child A -> View Child A -> Click a floating, transparent Next button/view -> Push Child B -> etc...

I haven't seen any examples of this navigation in any sample code - is this possible or are there some hidden gotchas?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086381/uinavigationcontroller-going-directly-to-next-controller

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible, but you'll probably have to create a custom UIView subclass to be able to handle the Next/Previous buttons. This custom class would pop the current view and call a method in the parent TableView to push the appropriate UITableView onto the stack.